# How do I transfer a named attribute from one point to another by index lookup?

Tags: geometry-nodes, simulation-nodes

I'm trying to re-implement a [space colonization](http://algorithmicbotany.org/papers/colonization.egwnp2007.large.pdf) approach in Geometry nodes, and I'm having a ton of trouble trying to get the data flow working correctly.

I've scattered "food" points, and "spawn" points. The food points find their nearest spawn point, and it is stored as a named attribute on the points themselves. A direction vector from the spawn point to each food point that's marked it as "nearest" is stored on the food points.

Each food point then gets assigned the summed and normalized direction vector from its spawn point to all food points shared by that spawn point.

I'm stuck at how to transfer it back to the spawn point.

What I want to do:

For the spawn point with the index of 4053, look up the accumulated "pointing_vector" attribute from any of the points that have "4053" as their "nearest_node" attribute, and assign that vector to the spawn point's "pointing_vector" attribute.

Eventually I want to dump this into a simulation zone so it'll grow, but I need to be able to transfer this data first...

**[Edit]**
Here's the full .blend file for context:

[image]

---

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hello. Could you share your file in order to have all the context of the question?

Comment: @lemon Sure! Just added it. Thanks for taking a look!